# How do I create a desktop shortcut for GoG Galaxy games after installing them?

Tags: windows, gog, gog-galaxy

Apparently, you can create a shortcut when first installing a game using GoG Galaxy. I forgot to enable that option for Witcher 3 when installing it, so I don't have a shortcut on my desktop.

According to their forums (http://www.gog.com/forum/general/desktop_shortcut/post4), you can enable an option in the settings menu (the cog on the bottom-left), but either I'm blind and can't see it or you need to enable something else as well.

[image]

I can see "run on startup", "automatic bug reports", "preview updates", "no minimize", concurrent connections, startup page, language, some features that are coming soon and some folder locations. I don't see how to configure a desktop shortcut.

How can I create such shortcuts?

Comment: You're right I don't seem to see the "install with desktop shortcuts" option as mentioned. But you can go to your C:\games\GOG.com\GalaxyClient\Games\ folders, find the game.exe or launcher.exe files, right click them and "Send -> To desktop (make a shortcut)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the feature has either been removed from the settings at some point (either accidentally, or for a reason), or was planned but not yet added.

Currently you can choose to create a shortcut the moment you install the game, like in the following screenshot:

[image]

---

If you've already installed the game and missed the opportunity to create a desktop shortcut, fret not: GOG will have automatically created a shortcut in your Start Menu.

Since GOG, unlike Steam, doesn't put shortcuts in a shared Start Menu folder, you'll have to search for it. Simply open the Start Menu and start typing the name of your game, for instance `Dark Souls` if you want a shortcut to your death.

From here, copying the shortcut to your desktop shouldn't be much more difficult than beating *Zelda 2*, though different OS and OS versions will require different methods.

- **Windows 7**: Simply right-click -> copy, then paste anywhere you like.
- **Windows 8, 8.1, 10**: Right-click -> `Open file location`. This will open a File Explorer window to where the shortcut is located. From there, just copy and paste the shortcut wherever you wish.

All that's left to do now is hope GOG will eventually give us an easier way to create shortcuts. In the meantime... did you go to the toilet before visiting Tartarus?